# Inject mock objects using PHP-DI for testing controllers with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, phpunit, php-di

I have refactored some of my controllers to use dependency injection via property injection [as recommended in the "best practices"](http://php-di.org/doc/best-practices.html#writing-controllers):

```
final class ZebraController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var AnimalClientInterface
     */
    private $animalsRestClient;

    public function fetchAllZebras(ServerRequestInterface $req): ResponseInterface {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My PHP-DI configuration is configured to inject an instance of the `AnimalClient` object for `AnimalClientInterface`, which is fine in implementation code as there is only 1 real `AnimalClient`.

In my unit test I need to inject a `MockZebraClient` into this property. I cannot simply configure it like I do for the `AnimalClient` because other classes might be annotated similarly but need, for example, a `MockTigerClient` for testing.

This is my unit test:

```
class ZebraControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @var ZebraController */
    protected $object;

    public function testFetchAllZebras(): void {
        // assertions here
    }
}
```

I think that using the [`injectOn` method](http://php-di.org/doc/inject-on-instance.html) is the correct way to approach this problem but I don't know how to configure the container to choose the correct mock object for the correct test.

Constructor injection isn't possible due to the legacy code structure. All the controllers in the application would need to be refactored to use DI in order to change the constructor of `Controller`.

Comment: Not familiar with PHP-DI, but you could always add a constructor and call it in your tests.

Comment: @JohnV. Unfortunately I can't change the method signature of the `Controller` constructor due to the legacy structure of the code. Overriding it in the child class to add more parameters isn't an option either until all controllers in the codebase are refactored to use DI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a PHP-DI specific answer, but I am unfamilar with it. It also seems defining a constructor is not allowed in your case. Given that, you can use a static pretend constructor for testing, which allows access to setting internal state:

```
<?php
class A {
    private $b;

    public static function construct($b) {
        $a = new A();
        $a->b = $b;
        return $a;
    }
}

class B {

}

$a = A::construct(new B());
var_dump($a);
```

Returns:

> object(A)#2 (1) {   ["b":"A":private]=>   object(B)#1 (0) {   } }